# How to add a global default panelClass to angular material select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to change the `mat-select`'s dropdown's position slightly , currently I have to add a class to `panelClass` option for every `mat-select` instance ...

Is there any way to add this class globally?

I tried using `MAT_SELECT_CONFIG` but it only has 2 props

```
export interface MatSelectConfig {
    /** Whether option centering should be disabled. */
    disableOptionCentering?: boolean;
    /** Time to wait in milliseconds after the last keystroke before moving focus to an item. */
    typeaheadDebounceInterval?: number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No ways,
Here is a workaround

```
import {Directive, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSelect} from '@angular/material/select';

@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-select'
})
export class CustomSelectDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(MatSelect) private select: MatSelect) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.select.panelClass = 'your class';
  }
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-apply-panel-class?file=src/styles.scss)

Comment: Has this been tested?

Comment: I created [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-apply-panel-class?file=src/styles.scss)

Answer (score 2):

globally you can set it with:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_SELECT_CONFIG,
      useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'customClass' }
    }
  ],
```

[MAT_SELECT_CONFIG](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e2a0b9e941580e83081251889f671a572d62f245/src/material/select/select.ts#L165) has such property

```
/** Object that can be used to configure the default options for the select module. */
export interface MatSelectConfig {
  /** Whether option centering should be disabled. */
  disableOptionCentering?: boolean;

  /** Time to wait in milliseconds after the last keystroke before moving focus to an item. */
  typeaheadDebounceInterval?: number;

  /** Class or list of classes to be applied to the menu's overlay panel. */
  overlayPanelClass?: string | string[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `::ng-deep` styling for select in styles.scss.